# How chkdsk can scan or repair files if volume still being used?

Tags: windows-7, chkdsk

We all know chkdsk /r wont work after welcome screen, It shows like this:
[image]

but before welcome screen & after win 7 glowing screen chkdsk /r works, why?

before welcome screen also volume is being used, that is why we can see glowing screen, then how chkdsk /r works?

Comment: The volume during boot is initially in read-only mode.  Once the volume is mounted in read/write mode, then chkdsk  cannot modify/repair the volume.

Comment: Chkdsk works on very low level. When it needs to fix file system problems, it must write to disk. Writing to mounted file system and using it from OS same time is dangerous, so chkdsk tries to be safe and writes to file system before it mounted in read/write mode. Same rule applies to any well known file system on any OS AFAIK. For non system partition Windows unmounts it, locks, then chkdsk will work. For system partition Windows cannot unmount it after boot, so You need reboot and chkdsk will be done in pre OS boot mode.

Answer (score 2):

As was stated in the answer by Daniel: **`chkdsk` cannot check a disk that is in use.**
Also: `Would you like to schedule this volume to be checked the next time the system restarts? (Y/N)` should be answered with **`y`** as that ensures that the system will not be in use during `chkdsk`.
Need to keep in mind that the chkdsk command might run for

1. a fairly long time (several hours to a few days,)
2. multiple times (2 to 3 times,)
3. and might seem to be stuck at times

I just finished a chkdsk on an older windows 7 system that ultimately ran for over 12 hours with at least 3 restarts of the chkdsk. I had responded `y` to the question of checking the next time the system restarts and restarted the system myself.
There were corruptions in the fs and the indices which were fixed. Currently the system is running somewhat sluggish as the system cache needs to be rebuilt.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done, because `chkdsk` cannot check a disk that is in use.  It must first unmount the partition.

If you want a volume checked, it is best to either unmount it (also called `Eject`) yourself if it doesn't automatically, or to schedule it for the next system restart.  If you chose to schedule it for the next restart, then the next time your system boots it will run chkdsk.